# overlaying exponential distribution onto histogram

Tags: r, histogram, exponential-distribution

How can i overlay an exponential distribution on a histogram of time intervals? The histogram looks like an exponential distribution.
When I try to create the histogram in a similar way to superimposing a normal curve I get the following:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I can create the histogram on its own which has an x axis from 0 to 70. And I can create an exponential distribution curve on its own but its x axis goes from 0 to 1.

I am using `hist(t)` where `t` is a list of times in seconds for the histogram
and `curve(dexp(x,rate=0.09))` for the exponential distribution.

Comment: Can you provide `t`? I.e. using `dput(t)`

Comment: Are you using `prob = TRUE` in `hist`, and `add = TRUE` in `curve`?

Comment: @RichardScriven - you should make that an answer. Use `x <- rexp(300,rate=0.09)` as the example data and it works perfectly.

Comment: To avoid confusion with the expression in `curve`, I went with `z <- rexp(...)`.  It actually removes the ugly upward line at the beginning.  Weird.

Comment: @RichardScriven - it makes no difference if `x` or `z` - the change is due to re-running `rexp` which is random and will change the data each time. Try re-running your code multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use `prob = TRUE` in `hist`, and `add = TRUE` in `curve`

```
z <- rexp(300,rate = 0.09)
hist(z, prob = TRUE)
curve(dexp(x, rate = 0.09), col = 2, lty = 2, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder how many times this has been asked answered and duplicated?

Comment: I didn't check.  It was suggested in the comments that I answer the question, so I did.  I imagine quite a few, though. :)

Comment: The SO interface does not reward searching for duplicates. But it should.